# C# async, await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have simple code which I want to be executed asynchrounously:

```
public async Task EncryptAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // shift bytes
        // column multiplication
        // and so on
    }
}
```

That is the way I call above method:

```
private async void Encryption()
{
    ShowBusyIndicator();

    await encryptor.EncryptAsync();

    HideBusyIndicator();
}
```

The point is, when I add `await Task.Delay(1000);` in this method, busi indicator is shown, but after 1 sec, application locks and waits SYNCHRONOUSLY for encryption complete. If I remove Task.Delay, application lock and unlocks after operation finished.

How to use properly await and asyc in my case? I want simply execute method `encryptor.EncryptAsync()` asynchronously.

Comment: Note the compiler warning that your code gives.

Comment: Cryptography is **hard**.  Do not invent your own encryption.

Comment: It's just a feature for shiny and fancy looking :P

Comment: That's even worse.  **Do not mislead your users into thinking that you will actually protect their data**.  Creating a real security product along these lines is an extremely complicated task.  Read Bruce Schneier's blog.

Comment: It's just a student's application. Simple, without any complex logic and secure systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `async` / `await` keywords do not allow you to *create* new asynchrony; instead, they simply allow you to wait for an existing asynchronous operation to complete.

You want to run your CPU-bound operation on a background thread to avoid blocking the UI.
To do that, call the synchronous blocking method inside a lambda passed to `Task.Run()`.

You can then use `await` to wait for the resulting asynchronous operation (a `Task` instance).

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx that is very basic article and good sample that contains waiting on async with Task that return int

Comment: I wrote:

    private async void Encryption()
    {
        ShowBusyIndicator();

        await Task.Run(() => encryptor.EncryptAsync());

        HideBusyIndicator();
    }

Works!

Comment: Why do you await on Task.Run ?

Comment: @ilansch: To make `HideBusyIndicator()` run after the task finishes.

Comment: Pardon me asking but if you await a task, doesnt it start the task and wait for it to complete before heading the next line ?

Comment: @ilansch: `await` won't start the task.  Other than that, yes.

Comment: @ilansch: awaiting a task waits for it to complete before going on to the next line, but *while it is waiting the current thread can do work*. It's an *asynchronous* wait.

Comment: eric this is excatly what I meant, the invoked method will run async (the caller method is with async in its signature - thats why i must implement await inside of it), When i develop this way - The task whom i do the await on - starts on new thread in order to avoid blocking, and when it finishes the code jump to next line, i never do Task.Run only await on Task<T>, so why SLaks write it wont start the task ? this is confusing me.

Comment: Clarification, If he has a method Task EncryptAsync(), and he wants to run this method asynchronous and avoid blocking current thread, he do: await EncryptAsync(); - In his comment, he mentioned he is doing await Task.Run(() => encryptor.EncryptAsync()) - Why to do it with Task.Run and lambda if the function EncryptAsync() already returns Task ?

Comment: @ilansch: The problem is that his method isn't actually asynchronous.

Comment: ok I see. sorry didnt see its running sync', I thought he had more code, he should really use Treat warning as errors then this code simply wont compile and will be clearer. thanks.